# Moz-Proxy prompt Issues with FF22

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

While running my Automation scripts on FF22, using company proxy network am getting the moz-proxy prompts which says "The proxy mox-proxy://proxy.abc.com:8080 is requesting username and password". After goggling I found few preference settings as below which is not working for me.

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

            firefoxProfile.setPreference("network.proxy.type",
                    ProxyType.SYSTEM.ordinal());
            firefoxProfile.setPreference("signon.autologin.proxy", true);
            firefoxProfile.setPreference("network.websocket.enabled", false);
            firefoxProfile.setPreference("network.proxy.share_proxy_settings", false);
            firefoxProfile.setPreference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-proxies", false);
            firefoxProfile.setPreference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", "application url");
            firefoxProfile.setPreference("network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris", "application url");
            firefoxProfile.setPreference("network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris", "application url");
            firefoxProfile.setEnableNativeEvents(false);
            desiredCapabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE,
                    firefoxProfile);

            return new FirefoxDriver(desiredCapabilities);
```

am  using FF22 with Selenium 2.32 version.

Comment: I know I'm thinking work-around, but could you try to use [`driver.switchTo().alert().authenticateUsing(Credentials credentials)`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html#authenticateUsing%28org.openqa.selenium.security.Credentials%29)? It's a fairly new feature which, I think, has been working in Firefox.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.. randomly firefox prompts for proxy, earlier on FF17 I was getting prompts at the time of login, but in FF22 am getting at the time of Button clicks also which is not consistent..